# why don't the first cell run in the algorithm named Flow forecast

Tags: deep-learning, kaggle

I'm struggling to run the following code in Kaggle and I encounter an error in the first cell.

https://www.kaggle.com/code/isaacmg/multi-region-transformer

The error is:

```
> Cloning into 'flow-forecast'... fatal: unable to access
> 'https://github.com/AIStream-Peelout/flow-forecast.git/': Could not
> resolve host: github.com
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call
> last) /tmp/ipykernel_28/1352866601.py in <module>
>       3 import pandas as pd
>       4 get_ipython().system('git clone https://github.com/AIStream-Peelout/flow-forecast.git'
> class="ansi-blue-fg">)
> ----> 5 os.chdir("flow-forecast")
>       6 get_ipython().system('pip install -r requirements.txt')
>       7 get_ipython().system('python setup.py develop')
> 
> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
> 'flow-forecast'
```

I have also tried running the code in my own PC, but the problem exists

If you look at the Kaggle repository, the authors previously ran the code on Kaggle.

Answer (score 0):

Environment Restrictions: Some platforms or environments (like certain work or educational environments) might restrict access to external websites or version control systems. Check if there are any restrictions in the environment you're using.

Alternative Cloning Methods: Instead of using git clone within the code, you can download the repository as a ZIP file from GitHub directly and then manually upload and extract it into your environment.

Try Different Environment: If possible, try running the code in a different environment or platform to see if the issue persists.

But You Can Facing Same Problem in Kaggle You try to

using my shared google colab it can properly work

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1tGZ404QjdvLYNm-8NvxUUGlWXIoQkLYL?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks, It's the restriction by Kaggle, but how could the authors run the model on Kaggle?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy

Comment: kaggle are colab have the notebook provider same functionality have colab whitch is is kaggle only download the 1mb datasets file and upload the colab and use it.

Comment: how to run this code piece on colab?
from flood_forecast.trainer import train_function
from kaggle_secrets import UserSecretsClient
user_secrets = UserSecretsClient()
secret_value_0 = user_secrets.get_secret("WANDB_KEY")
os.environ["WANDB_API_KEY"] = secret_value_0
model = train_function("PyTorch", the_config)

Comment: it seems like "UserSecretsClient" is just for Kaggle

Comment: wait ok i will try to run this code in kaggle and share notebook hold it

Comment: Problem Of Kaggle Kaggle Cannot Clone Github Repo So you Can Same To Use The Google Colab Like Kaggle Left side in google colab have folder icon you can use to create  new file like enviroment file you can create and store data this file .

Comment: so, how can I implement the abovementioned code in Colab?

Comment: Can you please add the relevant piece of code into the Answer?